# Java: Having some problems with my file input/output (br cannot be resolved)

Tags: java, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

I'm relatively new to Java, so I'm just trying to get some practice with simple IO, as well as exception handling. My program is pretty basic - I just want to read a number from a file, and then convert it from Celsius to Fahreinheit, and output it on another file. The errors I'm getting are:  "br/bw cannot be resolved" and  "br/bw cannot be resolved to a variable." Seems like a scope issue, but I'm not sure. I say this because they are all occurring after I create the BufferedReader/BufferedWriter objects/variables.

Thanks for looking.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class InputOutputTest {

    public static void main (String [] args){

        String dataIn = "input.txt";
        String dataOut = "output.txt";

        try{
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( dataIn ) );
        }

        catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("Cannot open " + dataIn);

        }

        try{
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(dataOut));
        }

        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Cannot open " + dataOut);
        }

        Scanner fileIn = new Scanner( br );

        try{
            while(fileIn.hasNext()){

                int cTemp = fileIn.nextInt();
                int fTemp = cTemp * (9/5) + 32;

                bw.write("The temperature " + cTemp + " in fahrenheit is " + fTemp);
            }
        }

        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error, problem writing to file.");
        }

        try{
            br.close();
            bw.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e){System.out.println("Error: Problem closing input or output file.");}
    }
}
```

Comment: The scope of bw and br are within try block. You may want to read on scoping rules to understand that better.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I definitely should have caught that. Even though I'm new to Java, it is a very obvious scoping issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you've declared your `br` variable inside the `try` block, its scope is limited to that block.

To increase `br`'s scope, declare it before the `try` block.

```
BufferedReader br = null;
try{
    br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( dataIn ) );
}
```

You'll have to initialize it to `null` so you can be sure that it's always initialized to something (even `null`) before it's referenced for the first time.

Future references will need to check if it's `null` before using it.

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you declared BufferedReader within a try block, it is not visible outside of this block. In Java, scope resolution (determined by enclosing curly braces) determines the visibility of an object.